# Recovering shapefiles deleted by mistake from webmap

Tags: qgis2web

I'm not entirely sure where I put my shapefiles for my project, but the layer can't seem to find them anymore.  Regardless, before I got rid of those layers, I exported the entire QGIS project as a webmap using QGIS2web, and all the data appears to still be there.

Is there an easy way to extract the shapefiles from the .js file in the data folder of my webmap project?

Comment: in the qgis2web exported folder there are layers.js files, embedded in them are GeoJSON, so you can extract to a .geo/json and load back into qgis.